# Object object print (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, printing

I got a few buttons on my website, they are onclicks and the js file looks like this (a little part for example):

```
var bestMovie = function () {
        document.getElementById("bestefilm").innerHTML = "The Fault In Our Stats | Budget: $12 miljoen - Opgeleverd: $65.3 miljoen";
    };

var buttonClick7 = document.querySelector(".bestefilm");
    buttonClick7.addEventListener("click", bestMovie);
```

and my html is like this:

```
  <input type="button" class="bestefilm" value="Welke film heeft het meest opgeleverd in juni 2014?" />
  <p id="bestefilm"></p>
```

It works fine, but i also have added an array with objects, my js looks like this:

```
var top5Movies = function() {

    var movies = new Array(5);

    movies[0] = {title: "300: Rise Of An Empire", iMDBscore: "6.6", number: "#1"};
    movies[1] = {title: "Street Fighter: Assassin's Fist", iMDBscore: "8.2", number: "#2"};
    movies[2] = {title: "X-Men: Days of Future Past", iMDBscore: "8.5", number: "#3"};
    movies[3] = {title: "The Grand Budapest Hotel", iMDBscore: "8.3", number: "#4"};
    movies[4] = {title: "Non-stop", iMDBscore: "7.2", number: "#5"};

    var geefAntwoord = movies[Math.round((movies.length - 1) * Math.random())];

    var genereerRandom = document.getElementById("random1");
    genereerRandom.innerHTML = geefAntwoord;
}

var buttonClick8 = document.querySelector(".random1")
buttonClick8.addEventListener("click", top5Movies);
```

and my HTML like this:

```
  <input type="button" class="random1" value="Willekeurige selectie van 5 films die het meest zijn gedownload in juni 2014" />
  <p id="random1"></p>
```

The thing is, when i press the button 'willekeurige selectie..' which means 'a random selection' i get this answer: [object Object].

How can i fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I am new to Javascript, and i did not understand anything of what you have said sir.

Comment: If you want to put the movie title in the HTML, use `genereerRandom.innerHTML = geefAntwoord.title`

Comment: @user3744192 In the console, try: `var x = {}; "" + x` - you'll see the same [object Object].

Comment: geefAntwoord (what you set as the innerHTML) is a JSON object. Thus, you see [object Object].

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
genereerRandom.innerHTML = geefAntwoord;
```

With

```
genereerRandom.innerHTML = geefAntwoord.title;
```

And also see [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)